# R: Row-wise expansion of data frame with consecutive integers

Tags: r, dataframe, integer

I have measured some positions `pos`, e.g.:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(8)
data <- 
  data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:5],
            pos=c(0,round(runif(4, 1, 10),0))) %>% 
  arrange(pos)
> data
  id pos
1  A   0
2  C   3
3  B   5
4  E   7
5  D   8
```

How can I expand a data frame like `data` with every possible `pos` (0,1,2,..,n) where n would be max(data$pos) (i.e. 8 in this example). I like to get something as:

```
    id  pos
1   A   0
2   NA  1
3   NA  2
4   C   3
5   NA  4
6   B   5
7   NA  6
8   E   7
9   D   8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways, but one way, in base R, is by using merge:

```
merge(data.frame(pos = 0:8), data, all.x = TRUE)
```

Or, using `dplyr`, it's:

```
data.frame(pos = 0:8) %>% left_join(data)
```

Comment: For the base R solution, although akrun's is just as simple.

Comment: perhaps, although I don't think data.table is base R either.

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(data)[data.table(pos=0:8), on='pos']
#    id pos
#1:  A   0
#2: NA   1
#3: NA   2
#4:  C   3
#5: NA   4
#6:  B   5
#7: NA   6
#8:  E   7
#9:  D   8
```